# Structure a large Aurelia application on ASPNET Core MVC

Tags: aurelia

I have started to work on a greenfield web project which will use ASPNET Core and Aurelia. I cannot find a definitive best-practice approach to structuring this on the client. My current thinking is that each app feature will be be a separate Aurelia application, i.e. when a visitor clicks on the link "Accounts" the browser will make a server request to https://example.com/accounts. This will return a single HTML page which bootstraps an Aurelia app just for accounts. All the accounts interaction will be delivered using Aurelia. Similarly, if the visitor then clicks on "Dashboard", another server roundtrip will bootstrap the "Dashboard" Aurelia app.

**Is this a good way of approaching the problem?** I have some concerns around application state - in that there will be cross-cutting concerns and data which I don't want to keep round-tripping to the server every time I need it, e.g. audit logs, user information.

**I see that Aurelia has the concept of Features** - semantically this is exactly what I want as each of these areas of the app will be delivered as a feature. However, I cannot find any good examples of the use of Aurelia features.

Any comments or experiences in similar projects most welcome.

Comment: This is quite a broad question. The whole point of a SPA is to allow you to create Routes & Views and not need to query pages from the server every time the URL changes. I'd say unless there's a distinct business need to have those things (Dashboard, Accounts, etc) as separate applications - I'd keep them as one.

Comment: I agree with thebluefox. The main purpose of an SPA is for it to be SP (Single Page). You often see people starting up a new app per page, but that is usually because they are moving towards an SPA, but cannot switch yet, because of history...

Comment: Thanks for your comments and I do appreciate the broadness of the question. I am new to SPAs as you can probably tell so perhaps I am hanging onto the server-side way of thinking. Would Aurelia Features then be a good way to organise the main areas of my application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the 'best' way of doing it but a lot of the applications I build are user / admin type products.

Rather than building an application for each side I take advantage of child routers and structure my application with a page based convention as described here:

https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/10/how-to-structure-an-aurelia-application/